# How to iterate over a column in MYSQL to derive the top 3 values by simultaneously by looking at a categorical column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How do I extract the top 3 customer ids for each country based on the profit column? (Screenshot_1 for reference)

I tried with rank function: `rank () over (partition by table_1.name order by profit desc) as ranks`, but it didn't work. It generated duplicate values for some reason.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions. You want the top 3 customers *per country*, so you need to `partition by country`, not by `name`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by country order by profit desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 3
```

If you want to allow ties (which might give you more than 3 customers per country), then you can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` (the rest of the query remains the same).

Please note that window functions are available in MySL 8.0 only.

Comment: In this table, I just called it to name instead of the country name. I performed the exact same thing what you mentioned, but it didn't work

Comment: @ArunAnanda: ok my bad, that was not explicit in your question (it can only be seen in the image). Anyway, the above query should do what you want (assuming you are running MySQL 8.0): give it a shot!